# Why isn't there an AuthenticationFilterAttribute class in ASP.NET Web API 2?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

ASP.NET Web API 2 comes with [five filter interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.filters.aspx):

- `IActionFilter`
- `IAuthenticationFilter`
- `IAuthorizationFilter`
- `IExceptionFilter`
- `IOverrideFilter`

All of those interfaces have built-in implementations (e.g. `ActionFilterAttribute`, `AuthorizationFilterAttribute`), except for `IAuthenticationFilter`. Is there a reason for that or have Web API devs simply forgot to provide an implementation for that particular interface?

**UPDATE**

After reading Yishai Galatzer's answer I ended up implementing the "missing" attribute and uploaded it to Nuget.org: https://www.nuget.org/packages/WebApi.AuthenticationFilter

Comment: I assume there's no `AuthenticationFilterAttribute` because you can fulfill the use-case by using the `AuthorizationFilterAttribute` (assuming the use-case is you only "authorize" people who have authenticated)

Comment: To elaborate further, authorization is the process of granting access, authentication can then be used to determine authorization.

Comment: @Matthew The `IAuthenticationFilter` interface was introduced in v2 so you don't have to use an authorization filter to perform both authentication and authorization, which is indeed a good thing. What I don't quite understand is why they haven't provided an implementation for that new interface so that I can subclass it and implement my custom authentication the same way as I do for custom authorization.

Comment: @Matthew I certainly can implement `IAuthenticationFilter` myself and it will work just fine. But for me it would be more consistent to subclass a `FilterAttribute` class as it's usually done with all other filters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because we don't expect the common user to use an AuthenticationFilter. This is a way of not putting it front and center.