# ActionContext.ActionArguments Is Empty In IAuthenticationFilter

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, asp.net-web-api2, action-filter

**Background:**

I want to authenticate a POST request to my web API using an implementation of `IAuthenticationFilter` injected using Ninject. To authenticate a request I need access to request body.

**Problem:**

`ActionContext.ActionArguments`, which I usually use to access request payload, is empty when I try to access it inside the filter.

**Question:**

1. How to access POST request payload inside an `IAuthenticationFilter` implementation?
2. Why `ActionContext.ActionArguments` is empty inside an `IAuthenticationFilter` implementation, but has values if my filter implements `ActionFilterAttribute`?

**Code:**

Filter implementation:

```
public class AuthenticateFilter : IAuthenticationFilter
{
    private const string AuthenticationHeader = "X-Auth-Token";
    private const string UserHeader = "X-Auth-User";

    private readonly ILog log;

    public AuthenticateFilter(ILog log)
    {
        this.log = log;
    }

    public Task AuthenticateAsync(HttpAuthenticationContext context, 
                                  CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // context.ActionContext.ActionArguments is empty

        if (!IsAuthenticated(context))
        {
            context.ErrorResult = 
                new StatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, 
                                     context.Request);
        }

        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }

    public Task ChallengeAsync(HttpAuthenticationChallengeContext context,
                               CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        context.Result = 
            new StatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, 
                                 context.Request);

        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }

    private bool IsAuthenticated(HttpAuthenticationContext context)
    {
        // Authentication code here
        // context.ActionContext.ActionArguments is empty
    }
}
```

The filter is injected using Ninject when controller method has a attribute.

```
kernel.BindHttpFilter<AuthenticateFilter>(FilterScope.Action)
      .WhenActionMethodHas<AuthenticateAttribute>();
```

`AuthenticateAttribute` is an empty `ActionFilterAttribute`.

```
public class AuthenticateAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{

}
```

Thank you!

Comment: (1) Does it work if you (temporarily) don't use Ninject? (2) Does it work if you use an Authorization filter? (3) Might be worth having a look at [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23554515/why-isnt-there-an-authenticationfilterattribute-class-in-asp-net-web-api-2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected behavior. `Authentication` and `Authorization` filters run before ModelBinding/Formatter deserialization stage, where as `Action` filters run after this stage.

Comment: Got it. Is it possible to access request body at all in `Authentication` and `Authorization` filters or it is not recommended?

Comment: Yes, it possible to read the request body in `Authentication` and `Authorization` filters, but this is not usual...so can you describe more about your scenario...

Answer (score 2):

I struggled a bit myself with the same situation, in case it helps anyone, you need to use Reflection and System.Web.Helpers's Json.Decode:

```
 public Task AuthenticateAsync(HttpAuthenticationContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        HttpRequestMessage request = context.Request;
        var content = request.Content.ReadAsAsync(typeof(Object)).Result.ToString();
        var methodInfo = ((ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor)request.Properties["MS_HttpActionDescriptor"]).MethodInfo; // get the method descriptor

        if (methodInfo.GetParameters().Any())  //this will get the parameter types
        {
             var parameterType = methodInfo.GetParameters().First().ParameterType; //you iterate can through the parameters if you need
             var casted = Json.Decode(content, parameterType);  //convert the json content into the previous type (your parameter)
             //do something with your populated object :)
        }

        return Task.FromResult(context.Request);
    }
```

Comment: A little hacky, but I think it will work :) How do you host it? IIS? Self-host?